# Will not run correctly! Taking in the assignment types, and grades until negative number is entered to find the weighted grade. C programing

Tags: c

Here is the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
//identifiy variables
    float grade, total;
    total = 0;
    char type;
//prompt user for type of assignment
    printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
    scanf("%c", &type);
//prompt user for grade
    printf("Please enter grade:(##.#) ");
    scanf("%f", &grade);
//while grade>=0
    while (grade>=0) {
    //if Homework
        if (type == 'H') {
        //calculate grade
            grade = grade * 0.3;
        //calculate total
            total = grade + total;
        //prompt user for type of assignment
            printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
            scanf("%c", &type);
        //ask for new grade
            printf("\nPlease enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &grade);

   }
    //if Lab
        else if (type == 'L') {
        //calculate grade
            grade = grade* 0.15;
        //calculate total
            total = grade + total;
        //prompt user for type of assignment
            printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
            scanf("%c", &type);
        //ask for new grade
            printf("\nPlease enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &grade);
        }
    //if Quiz
        else if (type == 'Q') {
        //calculate grade
            grade = grade* 0.2;
        //calculate total
            total = grade + total;
        //prompt user for type of assignment
            printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
            scanf("%c", &type);
        //ask for new grade
            printf("Please enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &grade);
        }
    //if Exam
        else if (type == 'E') {
        //calculate grade
            grade = grade* 0.2;
        //calculate total
            total = grade + total;
        //prompt user for type of assignment
            printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
            scanf("%c", &type);
        //ask for new grade
            printf("\nPlease enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &grade);
        }
    //if Final
        else {
        //calculate grade
            grade = grade* 0.15;
        //calculate total
            total = grade + total;
        //prompt user for type of assignment
            printf("Please enter the type of Assignment: ");
            scanf("%c", &type);
        //ask for new grade
            printf("\nPlease enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &grade);
        }

    }
//print grade total
    printf("%f", total);
//check to see the final letter grade
    //if total>=90
    if (total>=90){
        printf(" A");
    }
    //if total>=80
    else if (total>=80) {
        printf(" B");
    }
    //if total>=70
    else if (total>=70){
        printf(" C");
    }
    //if total>=60
    else if (total>=60){
        printf(" D");
    }
    //else
    else{
        printf(" F");
    }

}
```

Heres the issue...

The computer allows you to input the assignment type and a grade. Then the computer prints the "Please enter the type of Assignment:" but dose not allow the user to input a type. It just skips straight to asking the user for a grade and allowing a grade input.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &type);` --> `scanf(" %c", &type);` to skip previous newline(white-space)

Comment: The problem is a common one; you enter a grade, then the `scanf("%c", &type)` reads the newline after the grade instead of the next line of input.  Use `scanf(" %c", &type)` to skip leading white space, including the newline.  Also test that `scanf()` worked and to debug, print the data that is read.